# How to properly initialize task_struct in the linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, task

I would like to add a custom uint8_t in the `struct task_struct` in the linux kernel 4.14.

I have modified the struct in [include/linux/sched.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14/source/include/linux/sched.h) with my additional field:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_CGROUPS
    /* disallow userland-initiated cgroup migration */
    unsigned            no_cgroup_migration:1;
#endif

    unsigned long           atomic_flags; /* Flags requiring atomic access. */

    struct restart_block        restart_block;

    pid_t               pid;
    pid_t               tgid;

    /*Custom field*/
    uint8_t my_custom_field;

#ifdef CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR
    /* Canary value for the -fstack-protector GCC feature: */
    unsigned long           stack_canary;
#endif
```

and added the following initialization code:

In include/linux/init_task.h, I did:

```
        INIT_NUMA_BALANCING(tsk)                    \
        INIT_KASAN(tsk)                         \
        INIT_LIVEPATCH(tsk)                     \
        INIT_TASK_SECURITY                      \
        .my_custom_field=0                              \
    }
```

and in kernel/fork.c, I made sure to initialize again the field to 0:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_LOCKDEP
    p->lockdep_depth = 0; /* no locks held yet */
    p->curr_chain_key = 0;
    p->lockdep_recursion = 0;
    lockdep_init_task(p);
#endif

#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_MUTEXES
    p->blocked_on = NULL; /* not blocked yet */
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_BCACHE
    p->sequential_io    = 0;
    p->sequential_io_avg    = 0;
#endif

    p->my_custom_field = 0;
    /* Perform scheduler related setup. Assign this task to a CPU. */
    retval = sched_fork(clone_flags, p);
    if (retval)
        goto bad_fork_cleanup_policy;

    retval = perf_event_init_task(p);
```

However, when I check the variable later inside the scheduler, I get various value, without having modified the field myself:

```
[    2.897772] Custom value is 2
[    2.901038] Custom value is 58
[    2.901524] Custom value is 58
[    2.901549] Custom value is 58
[    2.901581] Custom value is 58
[    2.901604] Custom value is 58
[    2.901634] Custom value is 2
[    2.902328] Custom value is 2
[    2.902672] Custom value is 58
[    2.902864] Custom value is 58
[    2.902998] Custom value is 58
[    2.904071] Custom value is 58
[    2.905519] Custom value is 58
[    2.905995] Custom value is 58
[    2.906466] Custom value is 2
[    2.907082] Custom value is 58
[    2.907677] Custom value is 58
```

But I need this value to be 0 unless I change it myself. What could be the cause of this? Did I forget something in the initialization?

Comment: did you find  a solution? I'm not sure where I should look to initialize the task_struct fields